# How to display all projects in the Project View in PHPStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, development-environment, zend-studio

In eclipse / Zend Studio the project manager displays per default all projects of the workspace (or of one of its Working Sets, if selected):

[image]

Now I'm looking for the according configuration in PHPStorm, that shows only one project per window:

[image]

How can I see all my projects in the project view of the same window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm does not support *multiple independent projects* in one window / frame:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

---

But ... you can list files from another project there (in Project View panel). If that is good enough, then just go to `Settings | Directories` and add desired folder as an **Additional Content Root**. P.S. This also means that the setting from current project will be applied to all content roots.